# Creating a trigger which performs an update on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have two tables - one is called `bookloan` and the other `bookcopy`. In the `bookloan` table I have `datetime` field called `dateReturned`, which is `null` by default and is filled only when a book is returned.
In the other table (`bookcopy`) I have a field is available, which value is changed to `0` when a book is taken. Now I want to change it back to `1` when a book is returned (when my `datetime` field is no longer `null` and was updated).

My problem is that my code for this purpose (posted below) doesn't work for some reason.

P.S I don't get any errors.

```
USE `libdb`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS libdb.bookloan_BEFORE_UPDATE$$
USE `libdb`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `libdb`.`bookloan_BEFORE_UPDATE`
 BEFORE UPDATE ON `bookloan` 
 FOR EACH ROW



BEGIN 

IF NEW.dateReturned <=> OLD.dateReturned THEN
UPDATE bookcopy 
SET  isAvailable = 1
WHERE bookcopy.idBookCopy = NEW.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK;
END IF;



END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please include the full code for the trigger.

Comment: Done, I edditet my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<=>` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is a null safe **equals** operator, although according to the description you need to "not equals" operator. Here, specifically, if you only want to check if it turns from null to a non-null value (or vise versa), you can use the logical [`xor` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor):

```
IF (NEW.dateReturned IS NULL) XOR (OLD.dateReturned IS NULL) THEN
```

Comment: thanks, this solved it for me. obviously  i had my condition wrong :)